# How to generate unique uuid using uuid5 method

Tags: python-2.7, unique, uuid, sha1

I want to generate unique uuids using uuid5 method in python. I am passing namespace as 'uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS' and name string as 'serial_number'.

The problem here is that namespace is constant and serial_number for each device is different. Now, when the application runs at different times it generate same uuid because namespace and name serial in input args become same.

I am thinking of adding timestamp in name string passed to uniquely identify each uuid.

Can you please suggest me any better alternative to always generate unique uuids. I am open to modify name argument in uuid5 method?

Python Code:

```
import uuid


def unique_uuid(self, *args):
    uuidStr = ''

    for arg in args:
        uuidStr += '-'.join(arg)

    return str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(uuidStr)))


# The serials are different for each device and doesn't change with time.
# Hence at different time same uuid are generated for same device.
# But I need to always have unique uuids regardless of serial or any input.
# Only uuid5 method is allowed for final uuid generation.
serials = ["abc123", "xyz456"]

print(unique_uuid(serials))
```

Example of same uuid at different timestamp using uuid5 method.
[image: Example of same uuid at different timestamp using uuid5 method]

Comment: what is your code till now?

Comment: Code added @jkhadka

Comment: Simple way is definetly adding a time stamp: `uuidStr += '-' + str(time.time())` before hashing.